# How can i develop mobile web app using visual studio 2012 and jquery with asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in asp.net and I have a project to build a mobile web app but firstly I want to design my app how can I do that help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is rather broad but you will will want to look at the following:

1. [Responsive Web Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) - Examples such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
2. [Conditional Loading](http://modernizr.com/) - Allowing you to load scripts dependant on what the [browser supports](http://yepnopejs.com/)

Those are the first two steps I would suggest. When you have more specific problems come back and ask those instead.